# How can I configure an Azure OpenAI resource so that one cannot spend more than some given amount of money on it?

Tags: azure-cost-management

I created several Azure OpenAI resources in my Azure account. I deployed GPT models in each of the Azure OpenAI resources. I access them via the Azure OpenAI Playground. How can I configure each Azure OpenAI resource so that one cannot spend more than 50 USD monthly on it?

I tried adding a budget, but I couldn't find an option to put a hard limit on the expenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot configure an Azure OpenAI resource so that one cannot spend more than some given amount of money on it, aside from resorting to automations:

[Answer](https://redd.it/15iko81) by Reddit user [flappers87](https://www.reddit.com/user/flappers87):

> If you're on PAYG [pay as you go], then you don't have hard limits.
>
> You can setup automation around budgets to disable/ delete resources when a certain budget threshold is met.

Note that https://openai.com/ does offer hard limit, in case one isn't forced to use GPT via Azure:

[image]